# you will be able to get treatment / This, shouldn't have been passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

the expression below on the picture

[image]

> Also, make sure that you travel with proper medical insurance so that
>   if you are sick or injured while traveling you will be able to **get
>   treatment**.

Shouldn't have been passive voice? but ***treatment*** is not ***past participle***

Comment: This is a good question, but please don't post pictures of text.  The picture adds nothing that couldn't have been expressed by just typing the sentence.

Answer (score 3):

Your example sentence:

> Also, make sure that you travel with proper medical insurance so that if you are sick or injured while traveling you will be able **to get treatment**.

No, you don't need any past participles, passive-voice constructions or anything like that. The sentence is absolutely fine as it stands. You're just failing to fully grasp the semantics of it. The word *treatment* there is a noun (a mass noun, to be more precise) which is basically just a short form of *medical treatment* (medical care given to a patient for an illness or injury). And the verb *to get* is used to mean *to receive*. So, we could actually paraphrase your sentence in the following way and it would mean exactly the same thing:

> Also, make sure that you travel with proper medical insurance so that if you are sick or injured while traveling you will be able **to receive medical treatment**.

If you want the word *treat* to be used as a past participle, then the full expression would be something like this: *to get treated for something*. Where *something* specifies what you want to be treated for. But I don't think it will work as well as the way the sentence is originally written:

> Also, make sure that you travel with proper medical insurance so that if you are sick or injured while traveling you will be able **to get treated for your injuries**.

I hope things make sense to you now. If you still have any questions, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: okay, now gets more clear. but if we eliminate "for your injuries" (the last expression) still it is right?

Comment: No. It would sound incomplete. How exactly are you going to get treated? With candy? Will you be treated well? You need more information because the verb **treat** in English can have many different meanings.

Comment: @FaridS If you eliminate "for your injuries" in the last expression, you would use the noun "treatment".  Which is exactly what the writer of your article has done.